# Can't save from some programs to non-Ubuntu drive

Tags: partitioning, external-hard-drive, python, ubuntu-16.04, save-as

I have a MacBook Pro dual booting Ubuntu 16.04 and Mac.

When running some programs in Ubuntu, I can only save files to my Ubuntu partition. This includes IDLE3.

I want to save files to a different partition and other external drives.

I can see the partition I want to save the files to on the Launcher.

[image: The save as screen]

The partitions I want to save files to are on the launcher, but cannot be found anywhere in the folders I can see on the save as screen.

[image: Partitions on Launcher I can't see on the save as window]

This link, [How can I save to an external HD, using IDLE3?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/748630/how-can-i-save-to-an-external-hd-using-idle3), is an answer to a similar problem on Ask Ubuntu. But as far as I can tell my disks are already mounted, which is why I can see them on the Launcher.

TLDR: How do I save files from programs like IDLE3 to my other partitions and external drives?

- Python 3.5.2
- 2009 MacBook Pro
- Dual Boot Ubuntu 16.04 and whatever Mac OS (I don't use Mac for anything any more)
- No Boot Camp
- 3 partitions (Ubuntu, Mac, FAT32)
- I want to save on to the FAT32 partition or any external drive

Comment: Are you saying that you can't save files there, or you can't select the desired partition in the UI in order to save files there?  Have you tried navigating to the mount point in the directory tree displayed (typically in the media or mnt folder)?

Comment: I can't select the desired partition in the UI.

I didn't realize I could look in those two folders you mentioned because I am a noob. I am looking there now

Comment: The partition can be accessed through mnt. Awesome! Thanks